# On the properties of the even and odd components of the function $f_n(x)=(n-1) \text{Li}_n\left(e^x\right)-x \text{Li}_{n-1}\left(e^x\right)$

Tags: polynomials, special-functions

Let's define

$$f_n(x)=(n-1)\operatorname{Li}_n\left(e^x\right)-x\operatorname{Li}_{n-1}\left(e^x\right)$$

$$feven_n(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2$$

$$fodd_n(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2$$

At even $n$ the even part is polynomial, the odd part is "pseudo-polynomial", at odd $n$ the even part is pseudo-polynomial, the odd part is polynomial.

What can be said about the roots of $feven_n(x)$ at odd $n$ and $fodd_n(x)$ at even $n$? How many are them, where are they located on the complex plane? What about linear combinations of pseudo-polynomials?

Comment: $feven_1(x)=0$ for $x=(2p+1)i\pi$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakkeroh, oh, thanks. I wonder whether the other orders also have infinite number of roots?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, seems, yes. Infinite number of roots each.